# Python nested list comprehension iterate over both list elements

Tags: python

Given the following list of lists which has a length of 2 :

```
cLists = [[(1.3, "30__[1.353, '12', 'weekly']_[1.35, '20', 'daily']"), (1.35, '0_Retrace_50_M')], [(1.34, "32__[1.34, '11', 'weekly']_[1.34, '12', 'daily']"), (1.3459, '1_Ret_50_W')]]

len(cLists)
2
```

I can use a list comprehension on list index 1 `cLists[1]` as follows:

```
[level_description[1] for level_description in cLists[1] 
                    if any(k in level_description[1] for k in ['daily','weekly','monthly'])]
```

However I am struggling to iterate over both elements of the list `cLists[0]` and `cLists[1]`

How do I iterate over both elements of this list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want a nested list of results to match the input, you can just nest your list comprehensions:

```py
[[ld[1] for ld in cList if any(k in ld[1] for k in ['daily','weekly','monthly'])] for cList in cLists]
```

Output:

```py
[
 ["30__[1.353, '12', 'weekly']_[1.35, '20', 'daily']"],
 ["32__[1.34, '11', 'weekly']_[1.34, '12', 'daily']"]
]
```

If you don't want a nested list, you just need to add a `for` expression over the `cLists` values:

```py
[ld[1] for cList in cLists for ld in cList if any(k in ld[1] for k in ['daily','weekly','monthly'])]
```

Output:

```py
[
 "30__[1.353, '12', 'weekly']_[1.35, '20', 'daily']",
 "32__[1.34, '11', 'weekly']_[1.34, '12', 'daily']"
]
```

Comment: This is the more pythonic answer than mine - does exactly the same thing in one line. Good one.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what your looking or not...

```
aa = []
for i in cLists:
    aa.append([level_description[1] for level_description in i 
                if any(k in level_description[1] for k in ['daily','weekly','monthly'])])
```

aa then being a list of matches.